# R OSRM Iso giving Error

Tags: r, sf, open-source-routing-machine

I'm trying to run `osrmIsodistance` and `osrmIsochrone` and keep getting the same error when I type a negative coordinate, been looking for an answer but couldn't find it. This is the code I'm running.

```
library(sf)
library(osrm)

iso_point <- tibble::tribble(
    ~place,       ~lat,     ~lon,
  "Montevideo", -34.906066,-56.193580) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat"),crs = 4326)

iso <- osrmIsochrone(loc = iso_point, 
                     breaks = seq(0,2000,200),
                     res = 30,
                     osrm.profile = "foot")
```

```
library(sf)
library(osrm)

iso_point <- tibble::tribble(
    ~place,       ~lat,     ~lon,
  "Montevideo", -34.906066,-56.193580) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat"),crs = 4326)

iso <- osrmIsodistance(loc = iso_point, 
                     breaks = seq(0,2000,200),
                     res = 30,
                     osrm.profile = "foot")


"Warning: An empty object is returned. 'loc' is too far from, the OSRM network.Error: cannot create a crs from an  object of class list"
```

The curious thing is that only happen with negative coordinates, the same lines of codes work for any positive positive coordinates, tried it in multiple cities of Europe and works, any clue or suggestion?

Comment: Has been reported as an issue on the github tracker: https://github.com/riatelab/osrm/issues/119

Comment: Apparently this has been fixed or worked-round in the latest version on github: https://github.com/riatelab/osrm/issues/119#issuecomment-1333155495